# Identify Duplos that were in the Red Bunny Purse

Tags: duplo

Can anyone tell me what Duplos were included in the Red Bunny Purse?  I believe that was purchased in 1984.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[Plush Red Bunny / Rabbit Storage Bag](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=1955-2) (Bricklink)

Bricklink only lists 1 gear item and no other elements, so I'm inclined to think Mr. Bunny came without any Duplo elements, you had to fill him with your own Duplo bricks.

[image]

Comment: Rebrickable also lists [this bunny](https://rebrickable.com/sets/1955-2/plush-red-bunny-rabbit-storage-bag/?inventory=1#parts) under "Gear > Storage"

Comment: As indicated in the top photo, the bunny was a "bonus" item sold with some other set. I don't recall ever seeing it sold by itself. One such offer definitely included 2355 Basic Set - Vehicles; don't know if there were others.

Comment: Relevant link for 2355: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2355-2

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was beginning to think the same thing.

Comment: I can't stand how cute this question is!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while -- I bought that set for my infant / toddler son probably around 1985.  As I recall, it included 20 or 30 duplo blocks, no special shapes, several primary colors.  There were enough blocks to fully stuff the bunny's innards, as I recall.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I also bought one for my son around that time.  I'm trying to sort out all the Legos that I have accumulated for my kids.